# Buck error using curl: due to protocol(http)

Tags: gerrit, sonatype, buck, maven-repository

Using Ubuntu-14.04LTS system and with the instructions provided in this [Link](https://mydoc-lang.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tools/Delete_Project_Plugin_for_Gerrit.html) i am trying to build the gerrit `delete-project.jar` file for my gerrit version-2.13, However during build it fails with below error.

```
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/inject/guice/4.1.0/guice-4.1.0.jar error using curl: Command '['curl', '--proxy-anyauth', '-ksfo', '/root/.gerritcodereview/buck-cache/downloaded-artifacts/guice-4.1.0.jar-eeb69005da379a10071aa4948c48d89250febb07', 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/inject/guice/4.1.0/guice-4.1.0.jar']' returned non-zero exit status 22 

Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/googlecode/javaewah/JavaEWAH/0.7.9/JavaEWAH-0.7.9-sources.jar error using curl: Command '['curl', '--proxy-anyauth', '-ksfo', '/root/.gerritcodereview/buck-cache/downloaded-artifacts/javaewah-0.7.9-src.jar-dd7152dbfe349ce0d4e311f5bf2fd91935e22f77', 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/googlecode/javaewah/JavaEWAH/0.7.9/JavaEWAH-0.7.9-sources.jar']' returned non-zero exit status 22
```

Workaround provided in this [Link](https://support.sonatype.com/hc/en-us/articles/360041287334) that `http` protocol changed to `https` Now for gerrit `buck` build where i need to modify the protocol? Because `cat plugins/delete-project/lib/gerrit/BUCK` i can't see the protocol to modify.

```
include_defs('//bucklets/maven_jar.bucklet')

VER = '2.13.9'
REPO = MAVEN_CENTRAL

maven_jar(
  name = 'plugin-api',
  id = 'com.google.gerrit:gerrit-plugin-api:' + VER,
  sha1 = 'a9b00025900f68c1f86036ea07591a2876b10c37',
  attach_source = False,
  repository = REPO,
  license = 'Apache2.0',
)

maven_jar(
  name = 'acceptance-framework',
  id = 'com.google.gerrit:gerrit-acceptance-framework:' + VER,
  sha1 = '53a6e2baca19303bbf3967b861cf9814323c31f6',
  license = 'Apache2.0',
  attach_source = False,
  repository = REPO,
)
```

Please guide me to modify the same. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated the `http` protocol to `https` from the below files and now it is working fine.

```
1) WORKSPACE 
2) tools/util.py
```